# Clear Wordpress cookies via javascript off-site

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, wordpress, cookies

For example, I have an Angularjs application at the root of my domain. Also I have a Wordpress blog in /wordpress path. I'm trying to implement shared session between Angular app and Wordpress blog. So, if you are logged out, I also want to clear Wordpress session. In my wp-config file I defined cookie variables:

```
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH','/');
```

In my logout function I call php file /wordpress/clear_cookies.php

```
$http.post('/wordpress/clear_cookies.php')
     .success(function(result) {
         console.log(result);
     });
```

My clear_cookies file:

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
     print_r($cookies);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
 echo json_encode('Success');
?>
```

It actually works, and when I'm going to /wordpress/ after logout I didn't see any cookies and admin bar. But if I try to navigate to /wordpress/wp-admin - admin dashboard opens! I know about Wordpress functions for logout, but I can't get it how to use their outside Wordpress. Any ideas?